# Accessing Einstein Dashboard on a Lighting Page in Winter'20 with getState API

Tags: lightning, einstein, winter20

I have a Lightning Page built that contains multiple Lightning components and an Einstein dashboard that can be customized by the user.

I can find the name of the dashboard via `wave:discover` and `wave:discoverResponse` events so that I know which dashboards are on the page.

I'd like to get the current state of the dashboard via recently introduced getState method https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_bi_dashboard_state.htm. Unfortunately this require finding the dashboard first via find as per docs:

```
    let dashboard = component.find('myDashboard');
    let config = {};

    dashboard.getState(config, function(res, err) {
        if (err) {
            component.set('v.gserrMessage', err);
        }
        if (res) {
            component.set('v.dashboardState', JSON.stringify(res.payload, null, 4));
        }
    });
}
```

This seems to be impossible from the sibling component on the page.

Is it possible to query the state of the dashboard that is embedded on the lightning page rather than embedded into a component?